# How to access a docker service from public net (internet)?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Docker swarm,
**Setup**: only the master node (public ip: 30.50.60.90 and intranet ip: 10.0.0.3) is on the internet and the worker nodes (intranet ip's: 10.0.0.6 and 10.0.0.9)  are on the intranet.

Service creation-

```
$docker service create \  
  --name my-nginx \
  --network my-overlay \
  --replicas 1 \
  -p 8080:80 \
  nginx:latest
```

Now, does hitting http://30.50.60.90:8080 from the internet work?
If it does then what is the role of routing mesh here?

Comment: Try using `-p 8080:80`

Comment: done - edited to  -p 8080:80

Answer (score 0):

If you don't configure your firewalls or router NAT to forward the port, it won't be accessible from the internet, no matter you know your public IP address. Your public IP address points to your router, however, from there, your router is hiding your local network, where your swarm is likely deployed. In order to access the port from the internet, you must configure NAT in your router to forward the ports to your computer, from there, your service should be accessible, as long as the containers are deployed.

For more information, check [Super User - What is port forwarding and what is it used for?](https://superuser.com/questions/284051/what-is-port-forwarding-and-what-is-it-used-for).

If you need a simple way to get your service over Internet, I would give [ngrok](http://ngrok.com/) a shot.

Comment: the master node is on public internet i.e accessible from net (router rules are taken care of using ip masquerading). so will the service be available through internet... and what will be the role of routing mesh.

Answer (score -1):

For access, a docker service needs reverse proxy because docker swarm runs service in the inner network. docker service IP is not public on the internet because service is running on the docker-machine, docker-machine is isolation form network.
you can setup Nginx or any load balancer for reverse proxy.

for example, reverse proxy in Nginx

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name hello.com www.hello.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://your_server_ip:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```